# MongoDB update multiple items with multiple changes

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is there any recommended way to update multiple items in MongoDB with one query ? I know that this is possible:

```
db.collection('mycollection').update({active: 1}, {$set: {active:0}}, {multi: true});
```

But in my case I want to update several documents with "unique" changes.

e.g. I want to combine these two queries into one:

```
db.collection('mycollection').update({
  id: 'my id'
}, {
  $set: {
    name: "new name"
  }
});

db.collection('mycolleciont').update({
  id: 'my second id'
}, {
  $set: {
    name: "new name two"
  }
});
```

Why ? I have a system which gets daily updates imported. The updates are mostly large so its around 200,000 Updates a day so currently I am executing 200,000 times the update query which takes a long time.

If its necessary to know: I am using Mongo 3 and nodeJS.

Comment: You are looking for [Bulk update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp/)